# как каждый элемент серии перевести в двоичную систему из шестнадцатиричной

Tags: python, pandas

подскажите, пожалуйста, как из 16й системы можно быстро перевести в двоичную.
Если по одному числу записывать, то всё ок, работает.

```
a = int('0x3AF4580', 16)
b = bin(a)
```

(где 3AF4580 число в 16й системе)
К серии применить не получается. В руку так перебирать 190 тыс шт. долго. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как ускорить процесс.

Comment: Цикл написать. Непонятно что вы называете «серией»

Comment: @AlexeyTen судя по тегу вопроса, это pandas Series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну так пишите не по одному, а на все серию:

вот у вас есть pandas.Series s:

```
     0
0   16
1   22
2  512
3    1
4   69
5   86
```

далее просто делаете:

```
s = s.apply(bin)
```

теперь s:

```
              0
0       0b10000
1       0b10110
2  0b1000000000
3           0b1
4     0b1000101
5     0b1010110
```

Если же у вас серия с явной шестнадцатиричгой записью:

```
      0
0   0xa
1  0x10
2  0xc8
3   0x1
4  0x2d
5  0x38
```

то перевести в двоичную можно так:

```
s = s.apply(int, base=16).apply(bin)
```

получаете s:

```
            0
0      0b1010
1     0b10000
2  0b11001000
3         0b1
4    0b101101
5    0b111000
```

Comment: большое спасибо!